# Isotope - styling is inconsistent on initial load

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using isotope for the news section of this site:

http://itps.websitesnewcastle.com/news/

When you first go onto it then the rows/columns are all messed up and everything just clashes with each other.

However, when you refresh the page or use the filters then the layout gets sorted out.

Does anybody have an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: I *think* that's what's happening is that isotope's doing its thing before the styling kicks in. The same thing happens on my isotope sites, but still I prefer it to other solutions I've tried.

Comment: Please go fix your [HTML errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://itps.websitesnewcastle.com/news/) first, otherwise no one in their right mind will even start to look for possible reasons of display errors.

Comment: I've added it to window.load instead of document.ready, that made things wok.